# How to flip axis of javafx slider

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I'm creating rulers using javafx by modifying css of javafx slider and I created something like this:

[image]

And I was trying to make this:

[image]

So I tried to rotate sliders by calling `setRotate()` method but it becomes like this:

[image]

Here is my code for sliders:

```
Slider hRuler = new Slider(0, 160, 10);
hRuler.showTickMarksProperty().setValue(true);
hRuler.showTickLabelsProperty().setValue(true);
hRuler.setRotate(180);

Slider vRuler = new Slider(0, 100, 10);
vRuler.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
vRuler.showTickMarksProperty().setValue(true);
vRuler.showTickLabelsProperty().setValue(true);
vRuler.setRotate(180);
```

And here is my css code for sliders:

```
.slider > .thumb,
.slider > .thumb:hover,
.slider:focused > .thumb{
    -fx-background-color: #ff6a6a;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 -23 0;
    -fx-padding: 1 1 0 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.slider:vertical > .thumb,
.slider:vertical > .thumb:hover,
.slider:vertical:focused > .thumb{
    -fx-background-color: #ff6a6a;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 -23 0 2;
    -fx-padding: 1 0 1 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.slider > .track,
.slider:vertical > .track {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.slider > .axis {
    -fx-tick-mark-stroke: transparent;
    -fx-tick-label-font-size: 0.833333em;
    -fx-tick-label-fill: #9a9a9a;
    -fx-background-color: #333;
}
```

Please suggest me how can I flip axis or rotate labels of these slider so that I can achieve expected results.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you have to set the side property of the axis (for left and top). The steps that are involved:

- let the slider have a custom style, f.i. axis-top/axis-left
- in css, define a rule for the axis contained in such a slider to set its side to top/left

The code:

```
Slider hRuler = new Slider(0, 160, 10);
hRuler.showTickMarksProperty().setValue(true);
hRuler.showTickLabelsProperty().setValue(true);
hRuler.getStyleClass().add("axis-top");

Slider vRuler = new Slider(0, 100, 10);
vRuler.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
vRuler.showTickMarksProperty().setValue(true);
vRuler.showTickLabelsProperty().setValue(true);
vRuler.getStyleClass().add("axis-left");
```

In css:

```
.slider.axis-top > .axis  {
    -fx-side: TOP;
}

.slider.axis-left > .axis {
    -fx-side: LEFT;
}
```

This can certainly be optimized, but should get you started.